# Cannot upload project on sheepit renderfarm

Tags: sheepit

Read Carefully.

I want to render my project on the free render farm sheepit. I created a account with a profile picture and downloaded the client and also signed into my client which I download with my sheepit account. In the sheepit get started page it says to render 10 frames in my computer then I can upload the full project. I don't know how do I let the sheepit client know I have rendered 10 frames in my projects or which project I am trying to upload and render in sheepit. I tried rendering 10 frames while keeping both sheepit client and blender open at the same time. It didn't work. Can anyone please answer me how do I upload and render my project on sheepit step-by-step.

> Just answer the steps to upload my projects on sheepit render farm. First read my full question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you have to render 10 of your own frames first, but that you have to render at least 10 of other people's frames first using the sheepit client. I would recommend rendering more then just the first 10 frames though because you don't want your points to go to the negatives. Leave your computer on overnight or whenever your not using it to help render other people's projects, and if you are using the GPU to render and your specs are at least decent, you will wake up with a good amount of points to use for your project. I hope this helps if you haven't figured it out by now.